# Redmine permissions to git repos with gitolite

Tags: git, acl, redmine, gitolite

- I use Redmine to browse the repositories of each project.
- These repos are managed by gitolite with a specific user (not git).
- Redmine seems read the repos with the user `git`
- So each newly created repo (with already branches & commits) bring me the error in Redmine

> 404 - The entry or revision was not found in the repository.
>
> Today my workaround is to regularly give access to `git` at all repos recursively

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:git:rX /home/my_gitolite_user/repositories/
```

**Is there a way to specify as which user should Redmine read the repos ?**

I'm sure there is a good and simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If the gitolite repositories are in the same machine that Redmine you can try this:

`sudo usermod -a -G gitolite www-data`  // gitolite is a user account to manage repositories

`sudo chmod -R g+rx /home/gitolite/repositories` // this is the location path in server machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
sudo usermod -a -G my_gitolite_group my_redmine_user
sudo chmod -R g+rX /home/my_gitolite_user/repositories
```

And changing the default UMASK (as [described in the official doc](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc.html#specific-variables), I didn't find it before):

```
nano /home/my_gitolite_user/.gitolite.rc
```

with

```
UMASK = 0027
```